# Create an application with only one db table

Tags: database

This is an odd question.

Assuming a highly db dependent application such as a forum or chat website. As the joints on huge tables could be expensive. Can we put everything into 1 table and avoid all joints, unions etc. By this, we only query one table and with proper indexes, it would be fast.

I know that nobody wants all eggs in one basket but what is the main logics that the developers avoid this scenario.

Comment: Depends on the schema I guess.

Comment: As long as the tables are properly indexed, doing a join is no more expensive than doing a query on a very wide table.  Combining tables that should instead be joined results in redundant data, which can lead to the opportunity for inconsistent data.  You should read about database normalization.